# Catching params using $httpBackend

Tags: angularjs, regex, httpbackend

Trying to get a Param from this url: /api/events/{id}

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/\/api\/events\/(.+)/, undefined, undefined, ['eventID'])
               .respond(function(method, url, data, headers, params) {
                    console.log('get-params: ', params);
                    return 'test';
                });
```

Also this ist not working for me:

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', /\/api\/events\/(.+)/).respond...
```

as of [AngularJS httpBackend Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) (Dynamic responses) this should be working. Am I missing something, or is this a bug?

The Callback is called with the url like: "/api/events/1" but the params allways remain `undefinded`.

**EDIT:**
This is to come in AngularJS Version 1.5.0

Comment: Try using a negated character class instead of a `.`: `/\/api\/events\/([^\/]+)/`.

Comment: Thanks, tried and failed as well. My Version is at: AngularJS v1.4.7. (Mock too) I might try the newest one.

Comment: Ok, found it, this feature will come in 1.5.0, wich is still under development. The Documentation is strangely default on this version.

Answer (score 1):

For AngularJS-Versions below 1.5.0 this might be a simple solution testing dynamic URL's with parameters:

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', /\/api\/events\/.+/)
                .respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {
                    var args = url.match(/\/api\/events\/(.+)/);
                    console.log('some Data', url, args);
                    console.log('First Arg: ', args[1]);
                    return args[1];
                });
```